# What does stack.pop() return?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, stack

I was trying the below problem:

> Given a list of daily temperatures `T`, return a list such that, for
>   each day in the input, tells you how many days you would have to wait
>   until a warmer temperature. If there is no future day for which this
>   is possible, put 0 instead.

For example, given the list of temperatures `T = [73, 74, 75, 71, 69, 72, 76, 73]`, your output should be `[1, 1, 4, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0]`.

I found this solution which works perfectly but I don't understand how do we get the index from the `stack.pop()` method? Doesn't it return the element value?

```
public class DailyTemperatures {
    public int[] dailyTemperatures(int[] temperatures) {
        int[] res = new int[temperatures.length];
        Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack();

        for (int i = 0; i < temperatures.length; i++) {
            while (!stack.isEmpty() && temperatures[i] > temperatures[stack.peek()]) {

                int index = stack.pop();//this line is my query

                res[index] = i - index;
            }
            stack.push(i);
        }

        for (int i : res) {
            System.out.println(" "+ i);
        }
        return res;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DailyTemperatures dailyTemperatures=new DailyTemperatures();
        int [] temp={73, 74, 75, 71, 69, 72, 76, 73};
        dailyTemperatures.dailyTemperatures(temp);

    }
}
```

I have added a comment in the code

Comment: The element that is at the top of the stack: it removes that element from the stack as well. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html#pop() Here the algorithm has constructed a stack of *indices*.

Comment: *you* are putting index into the stack, you are getting index out of the stack... index is just an integer, the stack can hold integers

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as Willem has mentioned [pop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html#pop()) removes top element from the stack and returns its value. So how are you obtaining the index? You need to note what the element removed represents. In this case, it represents the index from the temperatures array:

```
stack.push(i);
```

Note that it pushes i intead of temperatures[i], so you are actually storing indexes instead of values in the stack. The code basically pushes all indexes into the stack, and when the current temperature is greater than one on top of the stack, you remove it and mark the answer for that index, which is `i - index` (current day - older day with lower temperature).

Comment: Thanks @juvian  ..I was missing the part that we are inserting the index of the array and not the element itself...Thanks guys for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

The pop() operation would give you index value only if you define your stack to store it.

#your declaration of stack.

Stack < Integer > stack = new Stack();

#expected declaration of stack to store both value and index.

Stack<Integer[]> stack=new Stack();

As the dataType of your stack now is an Integer Array, while doing the push operation you can store the index as well as value.

also to mention, the pop() operation will now give an Integer[] as return value.